# php: MongoDB copy collection from database to another

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need help in copy one collection from one database to another. I search multiple times but didn't get any proper solution. All are using `copyTo` or simple find query inside insert. which are not the best solution.. Because `copyTo` blocks all my database operations. and insert takes too much time to copy data from one collection to another. Because I have millions of records in my collection.

I checked one command in mongoDB:

```
db.runCommand({renameCollection:'db1.collection_name', to: 'db2.collection_name'});
```

This command work properly in php but problem is that it removes collection from source and move all data to destination database. I want to retain this collection on source also. So, I can copy same collection to multiple databases.

Can anyone have better suggestion? Please help me in this script.

Comment: Hi, I found its solution by using its 'mongodump' any perticular database collection and then 'mongorestore' to any other database collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not willing to use copyTo, find inside insert will be your next fastest bet. Those are both native mongodb commands, you're not going to get faster than that

**Option 2**

While I maintain that find inside insert is the fastest you can get (aside from copyTo) another option, that has the added benefit of maintaining your indexes, is to use `mongodump` then `mongorestore` with a different collection name. Do this either from the server hosting your mongodb or provision a server for a short time near your mongodb so it will be fast

Comment: Thanks for reply, But sorry, I can't use this. because it takes much time.. If you have any other suggestion. Then please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty straightforward when using [bulk operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/).

For php, this is called [batch operations](http://php.net/manual/de/mongocollection.batchinsert.php). Simply get all documents from the source database (which will be treated as an array) and put them as a parameter to the `batchInsert` method.

If you only need to do this once, you can easily do it on the mongo shell:

```js
use sourceDb
var targetDb= db.getSiblingDB("targetDb")
var bulk = targetDb.targetCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
var docs = db.sourceCollection.find()
docs.forEach(
  function(doc){
    bulk.insert(doc);
  }
)
bulk.execute()
```

Note that this does not copy the indices, which you should either generate before or after above bulk operation.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I check this. but not working on too much data. Because I have millions of records.

Comment: You should execute the bulk operations every 100k records or sth like that.